# Google analytics scripts in OpenCart escape quotes

Tags: php, google-analytics, opencart2.x

I am using Opencart 2.0.3.1 and just adding google analytics code. But the script was not working because as I look into the html source, the single quotes in the scripts were escaped. And when I look into the setting in admin page, the script was always escaped each time I save the settings. Is this a bug in OpenCart or not?

The google analytics script in html source become like this:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[\\\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\\\']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,\\\'script\\\',\\\'//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js\\\',\\\'ga\\\');

ga(\\\'create\\\', \\\'UA-70982371-1\\\', \\\'auto\\\');
ga(\\\'send\\\', \\\'pageview\\\');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the GA code directly  into your header file. This is a known issue: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=81677

Comment: The better advice would be "don't use software that doesn't fix its' bugs in three years" - the ticket is from 2012 !

Comment: True that! Better switch to another platform.